# Why does match will not release the mutable borrow until end of it's expression?

Tags: rust

I want to return client, In this function in any circumstances the code will not continue after match so rust should allow returning client.

```
pub async fn call_query2(mut client: Client<Compat<TcpStream>>, query:&str) -> Result<(Vec<tiberius::Row>,Client<Compat<TcpStream>>),(tiberius::error::Error,Client<Compat<TcpStream>>)> {
    match client.query(query, &[]).await {
        Ok(stream) =>{
            match stream.into_first_result().await {
                Ok(rows) => Ok((rows,client)),
                Err(e) => Err((e,client))                
            }
        },
        Err(e) => Err((e,client))
    }    
}
```

but the compiler return this error message:

```
match client.query(query, &[]).await {
    |           ------------------------------
    |           |
    |           borrow of `client` occurs here
    |           a temporary with access to the borrow is created here ...
...
102 |         Err(e) => Err((e,client))
    |                          ^^^^^^ move out of `client` occurs here
103 |     }    
104 | }
    | - ... and the borrow might be used here, when that temporary is dropped and runs the destructor for type `Result<QueryStream<'_>, tiberius::error::Error>`
```

It seems that match will not release the mutable borrow until end of it's expression, because this code will work but I'm not able to return client:

```
pub async fn call_query(mut client: Client<Compat<TcpStream>>, query:&str) -> Result<(Vec<tiberius::Row>,Client<Compat<TcpStream>>),tiberius::error::Error> {  
    let stream = client.query(query, &[]).await?;
    return  Ok((stream.into_first_result().await?,  client));
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is `Client` and `Client::query()`?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing more about `Client` and `Client::query()`, but probably the return value from `Client::query()` keeps a reference to client, and this return value will be dropped _after_ you try to put the client in the `Result`.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing is that the temporary value that is created with the match expression is not dropped (through the Drop trait) until after the match-expression.  In a sense you can think of the code being something like this:

```
pub async fn call_query2(mut client: Client<Compat<TcpStream>>, query:&str) -> Result<(Vec<tiberius::Row>,Client<Compat<TcpStream>>), (tiberius::error::Error,Client<Compat<TcpStream>>)> {    
    let result;
    let tmp = client.query(query, &[]).await; 
    match tmp {
        Ok(stream) => {
            match stream.into_first_result().await {
                Ok(rows) => result = Ok((rows,client)),
                Err(e) => result = Err((e,client))                
            }
        },
        Err(e) => result = Err((e,client))
    }    
    // tmp.drop(); happens here implicitly
    return result;
}
```

Note that the implicit call `tmp.drop()` here theoretically might need access to `client` from the borrow checker's perspective.

Your other example works because you're basically dropping result before the return statement. Conceptually something like this:

```
pub async fn call_query(mut client: Client<Compat<TcpStream>>, query:&str) -> Result<(Vec<tiberius::Row>,Client<Compat<TcpStream>>),tiberius::error::Error> {  
    let result = client.query(query, &[]).await;
    if let Err(e) = result {
        return Err( e );
    }    
    let stream = result.unwrap();
    return Ok((stream.into_first_result().await?,  client));    
}
```

Note that you couldn't return an `Err( (e,client) )` inside the if here either or you'd get again the same error from the borrow checker, since `result` hasn't been dropped yet.

That being said -- why would you want to return `client` in the first place? Probably because you want to use `client` in the calling code again.  But then your function shouldn't require the caller to give up ownership to client in the first place.  Just change `mut client: ...` in the signature of your function to `client: &mut ...` and remove `Client` from the return value type like this:

```
pub async fn call_query2(client: &mut Client<Compat<TcpStream>>, query:&str) -> Result<Vec<tiberius::Row>, tiberius::error::Error> {        
    // same code as before, but changing the result so that 
    // it doesn't return client anymore, i.e,
    // Ok( (rows,client) ) => Ok(rows) and same for Err
}
```

Now your calling code can still refer to `client` without needing it "passed back" from you function.  I.e., you go from

```
if let Ok( (rows, old_new_client) ) = call_query(client, query) {
     old_new_client.whatever();
}
```

to a much nicer

```
if let Ok(rows) = call_query2(&mut client, query) {
     client.whatever();
}
```

Comment: This version of call_query2() also lead to error.

Comment: Are you still returning client? I guess the "same code as before" comment in the code was  a bit misleading since the result returns need to be changed from Ok( (rows,client) ) to just Ok(rows).